# how to get US Highway exit geocodes using Google maps API or through some other means?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

For our application, we need to get all the US interstate highway exits along with their Geocodes. Can you please explain how to get these using Google Maps API or Google Local search or otherwise? So far I have no clue as to how to proceed. I greatly appreciate if you can point me in right direction.

I am looking for a free or a paid solution that is around $1000. I know there are people who provide geocodes. But they are out of our budget.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to extract the data you need from [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org). I shortly looked at the API they are providing, but it seems rather difficult to extract the data, although not impossible.

Comment: Good idea, and maybe not that hard. A quick export gives, for example :  <node id="41256904" lat="42.5092170" lon="-73.7909500" user="woodpeck_fixbot" uid="147510" visible="true" version="4" changeset="3430712" timestamp="2009-12-22T22:16:03Z">
  <tag k="highway" v="motorway_junction"/>
  <tag k="name" v="To 90E;Mass Turnpike;Boston"/>
  <tag k="ref" v="21A"/>
 </node>

Comment: I'll second OSM.  It's got a strong community, lots of accurate data, and a friendly license.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though GoogleMaps doesn't have this information.

However, you could take [this Excel spreadsheet](http://cms.transportation.org/?siteid=68&pageid=1760) from the AASHTPO and then use [my free geocoder addin for Excel](http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix/) to find all the intersections.

Here's a sample for the first 30 exits on Route 1:
[image]

It'll be a fair bit of work, and might not be perfectly accurate, but a very good start.

Comment: This looks good. What we need is something that is accurate. Since we are building a commercial app and we need to compete with our competitor's products that have accurate data, we also need to provide the same quality if not more. I will take a look at what you give here. Any suggestions on the paid solutions?

Comment: I have no idea how (in)accurate my proposal is. For the couple of cases that I examined, it was no more than a few hundred yards off, you'd need to test it more extensively. As for paid solutions, sorry, no, I'm not from the USA. If I were to do it, I'd buy a GPS DVD and figure out how to extract the data from it, but of course that raises IP issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily buy this data from Esri and it is very accurate stuff:
http://www.esri.com/products/index.html#data_panel

I also recommend checking on https://gis.stackexchange.com/, as someone there might know a free resource.

Answer (score 0):

[Tiger](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/)  - US census geo data

Its totally free to download and use but it would be and adventure. I'm not sure offhand if they highway off-ramps would be in it.

Comment: Tiger doesn't have this data.  I checked a couple days ago.  :-D

Answer (score -1):

I believe that some of the Wikipedia US highway articles have geocode information in them for each exit. A microformat extractor should be able to grab them for you.